How to generate a CFG, and each branch of the CFG has an expression that can reach this branch?
If I have a contract code (written in solidity language), I can easily use Slither to generate its CFG, but I want each branch of the CFG to have a conditional expression that can reach that branch. How should I do this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
